# Getting a drop-down menu from the Android title bar via Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin

I'm working on a cross-platform Android/iOS app via Xamarin.  I have an ActionBar, which is working.  But I can't get a drop-down menu to appear when I tap on the app title ("GraCal" in the screen shot).  How do I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
{
    ...

    ActionBar.SetHomeButtonEnabled (true);
}

public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected (IMenuItem item)
{
    switch (item.ItemId) {
    case Android.Resource.Id.Home:
        OpenOptionsMenu ();
        break;
    }
    return base.OnOptionsItemSelected (item);
}
```